# Strange MVC problem in VB.NET application with EditorFor method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a VB.NET MVC application and there I have the next code:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.UserName, New With {.class = "someClassName"})%>
```

which works fine on my dev machine, but returns this error after publishing the application to a QA server:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30311: Value
>   of type ' (line 91)'
>   cannot be converted to 'String'.

Also if I remove the second param in EditorFor method, it works, e.g.:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.UserName)%>
```

The error is same for Editor method.

Any ideas?

This is MVC 2 application on .NET 3.5

Update:

The problem not in name of the 'class' attribute in this case, as I checked other attributes as well without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `EditorFor` doesn't have the overload you are using.

The ones that have two arguments are:

`EditorFor(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>, Object)`

where the object is additional view data.

`EditorFor(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>, String)`

where the string is the template name.

The sad thing is that there isn't any overload that lets you add html attributes.

Comment: I've changed the answer entirely and I think I found the reason.